# System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException

Tags: antiforgerytoken

I am facing the anti forgery issue with three different error message:
1.The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.
2.The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
3. The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "userID".

What shall I do in order to stop these exceptions?